# How to send a form from a jquery ui dialog that does not contain the form inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following form with some data that I need to send.

```
<form action="http://localhost/sp/index.php/daily_operation/turn_close" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="form" name="form" class="form_cash"><br />           <input type="hidden" id="total_amount" name="total_amount" value="0">

                  <div>
                  <fieldset class="fieldset">

                  <legend>Billetes</legend>
                  <div class="row_form_div">
                      <label for="hundred_amount">100</label>
                      <input type="text" id="hundred_amount" name="hundred_amount" class="billet"/>
                      <input type="hidden" id="hundred_denomination_id" name="hundred_denomination_id" value="1">
                  </div>

                  <div class="row_form_div">
                      <label for="fith_amount">50</label>
                      <input type="text" name="fith_amount" id="fith_amount"  class="billet"/>
                      <input type="hidden" id="fith_denomination_id" name="fith_denomination_id" value="2">
                  </div>

                  <div class="row_form_div">
                      <label for="twenty_amount">20</label>
                      <input type="text" name="twenty_amount" id="twenty_amount" class="billet"/>
                      <input type="hidden" id="twenty_denomination_id" name="twenty_denomination_id" value="3">
                  </div>

                  <div class="row_form_div">
                      <label for="ten_amount">10</label>
                      <input type="text" name="ten_amount" id="ten_amount" class="billet"/>
                      <input type="hidden" id="ten_denomination_id" name="ten_denomination_id" value="4">
                  </div>

                  <div class="row_form_div">
                      <label for="five_amount">5</label>
                      <input type="text" name="five_amount" id="five_amount" class="billet"/>
                      <input type="hidden" id="five_denomination_id" name="five_denomination_id" value="5">
                  </div>

                  <div class="row_form_div">
                      <label for="one_amount">1</label>
                      <input type="text" name="one_amount" id="one_amount" class="billet"/>
                      <input type="hidden" id="one_denomination_id" name="one_denomination_id" value="6">
                  </div>

                 </fieldset>
                 </div>
</form>
```

Before sending it I need to ask for a condition with the data of the form.
I build a jquery ui dialog to ask for the condition

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="&iquest;Cerrar turno con diferencia?">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;">
            </span>El desglose insertado no coincide con el total por concepto de operaciones. Esto significa que cerrar&aacute; el turno con diferencia. 
            &iquest;Est&aacute; seguro?</p>
        </div>
```

That I call with the following JQuery code:

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen:false,
    height:150,
    width:340,
    open:false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "No": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Si": function() {
                $("#form").submit();
                $(this).dialog('close');
                }
        }
    }
});
```

This is with the aim to send the data posted in the form but nothings happens.

I have also tried to do this with Ajax

```
        "Si": function() {
                $("#form").submit();
                if (true) {
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: 'daily_operation/turn_close',
                            data: $("#form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                bValid = false;
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
        }
```

But remains without send nothing.

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is if you are trying to send it traditional way or by using AJAX

```
$("#form").submit();
```

This should send it but there are some problems (eg. IE requires that form contains submit button sic!). And this approach can create many problems. What i suggest is to use AJAX. For start try and see what happens.  :

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: 'daily_operation/turn_close',
                            data: $("#form").serialize(), 
                            beforeSend : function(){
                                  alert($("#form").serialize());
                            },
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                 alert(data);
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                bValid = false;
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: I can see that is sending the data by AJAX ok. I just need now to load the page that I need to be loaded after sending the post because it remains in the same page. Thanks a lot arbor.

Comment: but you are saying that method success is not called? Use firebug to see what comes back in your request. If you are using AJAX then you don't have to reload whole page just update some part of html. But you have to know what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of an old post, but I think I know why the form wasn't submitting. 
Instead of

`$("#form").submit();`

it should be

`$("#form")[0].submit();`.

`.submit()` is a built-in javascript function of the actual `form` HTML element. It should be used on the actual element. In pure JS:

```
document.getElementById("form").submit();
```

The jQuery `.submit()` is used for attaching functions to the `submit` event. Like:

```
$("#form").submit(function() { 
   return true; 
});
```

In jQuery you can use either the `.get()` function or the array index to get the actual HTML element. So this:

```
$("#form").get(0).submit();
```

should work too.